# dpkg: error: while installing video downloader

Tags: dpkg

I am very new in linux os NS get the following error message after installing snapd and libdvd-pkg-

`sudo apt install snapd`
get error message

dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory
libdvd-pkg: Package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed, stop processing...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

When executing command
`sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg`

get error message

dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory
libdvd-pkg: Package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed, stop processing...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

lastly tried command

`sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available`
get error
cp: cannot stat '/var/lib/dpkg/available-old': No such file or directory

again used commands

`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/available`
`sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/available`

and proceed with package installation:

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

tried to install
`sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg`

again get a lot of dpkg: warnings and message

````
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libapt-inst2.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtext-charwidth-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgcrypt20:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnginx-mod-stream' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwebp6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ca-certificates' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libstdc++6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsmartcols1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fdisk' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'util-linux' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgmp10:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmnl0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libidn2-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'apt-utils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libc6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nginx-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libaudit-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libselinux1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libx11-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnettle6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libp11-kit0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fontconfig-config' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'multiarch-support' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtinfo5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libbz2-1.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'update-motd' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libext2fs2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcap-ng0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ubuntu-keyring' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblocale-gettext-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libncursesw5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpcre3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'dpkg' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdb5.3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libaudit1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblzma5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'e2fsprogs' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libx11-6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnginx-mod-http-image-filter' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libseccomp2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libbsd0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpam-modules-bin' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsemanage-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libss2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libblkid1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libjpeg8:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'geoip-database' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libacl1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nginx' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgcc1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxcb1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'adduser' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'zlib1g:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmount1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'tar' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxpm4:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libhogweed4:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsemanage1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libfontconfig1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libudev1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpam-modules:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsepol1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnginx-mod-http-geoip' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nginx-core' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libunistring2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gcc-8-base:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxslt1.1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'apt' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'perl-base' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'openssl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnginx-mod-mail' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'sensible-utils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcom-err2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ucf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libapt-pkg5.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgpg-error0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpam0g:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgeoip1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'lsb-base' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtasn1-6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libuuid1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsystemd0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libffi6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gpgv' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxml2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libfreetype6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'coreutils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxdmcp6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'iproute2' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libssl1.1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libelf1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'debconf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtext-wrapi18n-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 0 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bsdutils_1%3a2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bsdutils (1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7) ...
Setting up bsdutils (1:2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package debianutils.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxau6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libapt-inst2.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtext-charwidth-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgcrypt20:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnginx-mod-stream' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libwebp6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ca-certificates' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libstdc++6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsmartcols1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fdisk' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'util-linux' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgmp10:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libmnl0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libidn2-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'apt-utils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libc6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nginx-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libaudit-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libselinux1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libx11-data' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnettle6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libp11-kit0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fontconfig-config' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'multiarch-support' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtinfo5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libbz2-1.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'update-motd' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libext2fs2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libcap-ng0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'ubuntu-keyring' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblocale-gettext-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libncursesw5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpcre3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'dpkg' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libdb5.3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libaudit1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblzma5:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'e2fsprogs' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libx11-6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libnginx-mod-http-image-filter' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libseccomp2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'iproute2' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libssl1.1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libelf1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'debconf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtext-wrapi18n-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 30 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../debianutils_4.8.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking debianutils (4.8.4) ...
Setting up debianutils (4.8.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcc1-0:amd64.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxau6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libapt-inst2.0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxml2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libfreetype6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'coreutils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libxdmcp6:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'iproute2' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libssl1.1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libelf1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'debconf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtext-wrapi18n-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YsVxqO/016-libglib2.0-0_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-YsVxqO/008-perl_5.26.1-6ubuntu0.5_amd64.deb
libdvd-pkg: Package libdvdcss2-1.4.2-1 was removed, stop processing...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```
````

Comment: You say "*very new in linux os NS*" but I don't know what that means. What OS & release are you using?  You mention various commands, but nothing about why you executed them, esp. given you're new (some seem dangerous to me for a newbie, so why?).  You're best starting with basics, what OS & release are you using?  What do you get with `sudo apt update` (scanning messages there are a huge clue as to problems that can occur.. esp. knowing your expected OS & release details).

Comment: Sorry. Mistakenly wrote NS, it’s ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. For video downloader.
`sudo snap install video-downloader`not worked. Followed [link]

(https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1826662)

installation failed.

sudo apt update reflects -
`Hit:1 ...                                                                         
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu bionic InRelease                         
Fetched 4,365 kB in 2s (1,891 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done`
@guiverc

Comment: Please edit & correct your own question, also when adding additional detail, please add it to your question. If those are the only messages you get on `sudo apt update` then a lot of lines are missing (which is very likely your issue... that detail is the first place I'd look for your problem as subsequent commands like `apt install` rely on the details obtained in the `apt update`.